# new table row in table

Tags: php, mysql

Can I create new table row in table for each  other table insert....

Like if i have two tables:

```
+-------+----------+--------+
   id   |   item1  |  item2 
+-------+----------+--------+
  user1 |  enum 0-1|enum 0-1
+-------+----------+--------+
  user2 | enum 0-1 |enum 0-1
```

And second one:

```
+-------+----------+
   id   |   item   
+-------+----------+
    1   |   item1
+-------+----------+
    2   |   item2
```

Now in table two:
When i insert new item like id=3 and item=item3
after that success - I need to make new row inside first table called item3 which is enum 0-1...
Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for syntax to add a column? Google : "MySQLI alter table add column"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ALTER TABLE table ADD item3 [insert appropriate datatype here]`

Followed by

`INSERT INTO table (id, item1, item2, item3, ...) VALUES ([id], [value], [value], [value],....)`

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, so i'll post it as an answer. In general you shouldn't dynamically alter tables. in your case you should have a third table which links the two together:

> Like if i have two tables:
>
> ```
> +-------+----------+--------+
>    id   |   item1  |  item2 
> +-------+----------+--------+
>   user1 |  enum 0-1|enum 0-1
> +-------+----------+--------+
>   user2 | enum 0-1 |enum 0-1
> ```
>
> And second one:
>
> ```
> +-------+----------+
>    id   |   item   
> +-------+----------+
>     1   |   item1
> +-------+----------+
>     2   |   item2
> ```

instead use this:

First table:

```
+-------+
   id   
+-------+
  user1 
+-------+
  user2
```

And second one:

```
+-------+----------+
   id   |   item   
+-------+----------+
    1   |   item1
+-------+----------+
    2   |   item2
```

Third one (rows filled as example):

```
+-------+-------------+----------+
   id   |   item_id   |  user_id
+-------+-------------+----------+
    1   |      1      |     2
+-------+-------------+----------+
    2   |      2      |     2
```

This is what you generally do to resolve many to many relationships
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity